# Proposal for Mathematics Learning, Studying, and Education

Tags: discussion, area51, math-educators-se

In view of https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12470/forum-for-chatty-math-education-questions, I thought to create this proposal. I'd appreciate your support and contributions. Please allow me to introduce it here and Math StackExchange to boot. Please let me know if this isn't welcomed here.

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64216/mathematics-learning-studying-and-education

Comment: @Dilaton, one such site is https://mathematicsteachingcommunity.math.uga.edu/.  (See the comment at https://mathematicsteachingcommunity.math.uga.edu/index.php/927/support-a-proposal-for-math-education-stackexchange#a929 )

Comment: @Dilaton, as for SE discouraging educational questions, I don't understand your point.  I would assume that majority of those on the internet have taken formal education and so would have an interest in how education can be improved.

Comment: @Dilaton, perhaps we have a misunderstanding due to terminology.  When you say "educational questions" are you referring to requests for answers to homework?

Comment: @Dilaton, It seems you misunderstood the scope of the proposed site.  It is meant to address mathematics education---how mathematics is learned and taught.  It is not about mathematics.  For example, the question "1+8=?" is a question about mathematics, and is off-topic for the site.  But the observation that "1+8" is more difficult to answer for very young children than "8+1" is about mathematics education, and is on-topic.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche ok, I removed my above comments ...

Comment: I think it would be nice to have a Math-Ed SE site. I'm not so keen on tinkering with Area 51, but I can point you to a few mathematics-education questions I have responded to on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/51285/where-and-when-did-transition-to-abstraction-courses-start/151910#151910  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/134796/is-problem-solving-a-subject-to-be-taught/148795#148795 and http://mathoverflow.net/a/135192/22971 Maybe this could be of some help... In fact, I argued for Math-Ed questions to be included on MO in an earlier meta post: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/291/22971

Answer (score 7):

This is an excellent idea!  For those not familiar with the area51 process, here's how you can help get this site off the ground:

1. Go to the site and click on "follow" in the upper left.  The site needs at least 60 followers to proceed to the next phase of the creation process.
2. **Upvote five of the questions**, and perhaps ask a few questions of your own.  The site needs at least 40 proposed questions with at least 10 upvotes each to proceed to the next phase of the creation process.
3. Comment on the merits of the questions, and join the discussion about the definition of the site.

See the [Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) for more information on the Stack Exchange site creation process.

**Update:** Only 11 more followers are needed!  If you do follow, please take a minute to upvote five of the questions.

Answer (score 1):

The definition phase of the proposal is almost done. Still a couple of votes are missing. Also the scope and the final name are discussed at the moment. If you want to influence the direction of that propsal right at the start now seems like a good time to join.

Comment: Meanwhile the "definition" is over, and it is in "commitment". (This does however not mean that everything is decided already.)