# The Math Teaching Stackexchange proposal is registering 38 more users for a private beta

Tags: discussion, area51, math-educators-se

**Edit:** Thanks to everyone who has signed up. There are already 162 participants, a number which usually takes several months to acheive.

As mentioned in [this post](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1426/proposal-for-mathematics-learning-studying-and-education), there is a [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64216/mathematics-learning-studying-and-education) on Area51 for a Math Teaching and Pedagogy Site. This site proposal has been successful up to this point, and is now registering 200 users for a short private beta (where users are asked to ask or answer 10 questions).

Input from people with a lot of teaching experience would be especially be interested. To commit or to see a list of sample questions, go to:
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64216/mathematics-learning-studying-and-education

Comment: Note: quid posted a similar notice in the first linked answer above, but it is difficult to know that registration has started from the post title alone. I would have edited that question if I had sufficient reputation.

Comment: It would be good, also, to get *experts* on math teaching/learning (in addition to practitioners of math teaching).  These might be psychologists or sociologists?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I agree it could be good to have more, but also we already have some (from the top of my head the MOers, Joel Reyes Noche and Benjamin Dickman). But, AFAIK, most experts in math teaching are actually (rather mainly) mathematicians. Sure, there might be some aspects of cognitive science and developmental psychology and alike that could be relevant sometimes, still I do not think there are many psychologists let alone socoiologists that are experts on mathematics teaching.

Comment: Only for the record, the proposal has now enough support to enter private beta, but one still can signup for it, AFAIK.